# rails engine ckeditor image upload causing exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have created an Engine including CKEditor.

Within my dummy application the form.cktext_area is working and rendering fine, however when I try to upload images I get the following exception:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create

Is this because I'm using CKEditor within an engine, in turn, causing some authentication/protection problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is a well documented problem. I've forgotten the actual cause but it's highly likely a part of your Rails stack isn't working properly (I think we had the issue with ImageMagick). Out of curiosity, are you using ActiveStorage in your app?

Comment: Hi Richard, I have of course looked and try to find a solution but did not find anything specific to my problem and was/am not sure if its to do with the engine. I am not using ImageMagick but am using the rmagick and mini_magick gems ... No I am not using ActiveStorage. Thanks, Jon.

Comment: If you use the ckeditor gem, it includes javascript to set the token on every request related to ckeditor. Maybe you are are missing some javascript requires in your application.js file? https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/dc2cef2c2c3358124ebd86ca2ef2335cc898b41f/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/filebrowser/javascripts/rails.js#L80

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the csrf token with your request, the easy way is to add csrf token in every ajax request:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function () {
  var csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
  if (csrfToken) {
    var obj = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(){
      var res = obj.apply(this, arguments);
      this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
      return res;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! however I am currently not using turbolinks - is this still the same problem ? thanks,

Comment: If you are not using `turbolinks` just replace the `turbolinks:load` with `document:load`. The problem is the same as before, you have to send the authenticity token with your request or disable CSRF protection in your rails application.

Comment: If this doesn't help, you're welcome to email me directly at rpeck@frontlineutilities.co.uk. I am sure I've fixed this problem before.

Comment: Hi guys thanks a lot for the help so far. I tried adding the csrf token to each request but it made no difference. To be sure I removed CKEdit from the project last night and re-added it. This removed this problem but introduced a new one: now when uploading an image I get: "NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<Pathname:/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/6/image.png>
Did you mean?  sub):" I assume because of its type pathname and not string? I also assume I'm experiencing such problems as I'm using the gem within an engine?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but removing CKEditor from my engine and re-adding it again solved this problem (I guess some installation/config problems from my side caused this).

Although now I'm facing and new problem ...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for #<Pathname:/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/6/image.png> Did you mean? sub):
```

.... which I will post as a new question if I can't fix it

Just to note, adding the csrf token to each request but it made no difference in my case.

Thanks for all your help and suggestions!